# Is it good habit to submit a community-wiki answer on behalf of asker?

Tags: discussion, identify, answers, community-wiki

Sometimes in an ID question, the asker finds out about the movie he is searching for and adds it in a comment rather than an answer and doesn't come back. So, in this kind of question, is adding a community-wiki answer a good habit or should I post a close vote?

In my opinion, I thought to post a community-wiki answer so that nobody gets any reputation advantage but our answer ratio remains good (Which we already lacking in). For instance I have done this twice in the following questions-

- [Soldier forced to kill captured prisoner](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8416/soldier-forced-to-kill-captured-prisoner/9338#9338)
- [Horror movie about a teenage boy and a haunted house with basement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14095/horror-movie-about-a-teenage-boy-and-a-haunted-house-with-basement)

So, is this a good habit?

Comment: This is actually not a bad idea.

Comment: I think this is a good idea too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely a good approach and a better one than merely close-voting it. But on the other hand if the asker doesn't come back, the question might get deleted for being an inactive ID-question sooner or later. But still, better an answered and unaccepted question than an unanswered one.

While it is a reasonable decision from you to make those answers community-wiki, I for myself (being quite rep-greedy) don't see this as a neccessary requirement (and am not a big fan of CW in general anyway), as long as the original contributor is paid credit in the answer text. If he is reluctant to post a proper answer, then there's no problem in posting one yourself.

Comment: This also applies for questions where users (often high-rep users) answer the question via the comments. As you say, while CW-ing an answer is fine, answering it yourself is better. It will encourage people (in the aforementioned scenario) to post answers rather than comment. In the case of MTV, I've seen this happening reasonably often in ID questions.

Comment: @coleopterist http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/682/what-is-this-sites-abreviation

Comment: @AnkitSharma That's cute :) But I'm too lazy to type an & every time. /me points at ELU, SFF, etc.

Comment: @coleopterist MTV is a famous music channel. So using M&Tv is good to Avoiding confusion.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yet while were at it, I find *"Tv"* much less intuitive than *"TV"*. ;-)